# Anchor tag to comment field

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

i have assigned an id to my comment field so that a click of a button scrolls to the comment area.

after the click the url gets the addition

https://url.de/#comments

I have implemented other social share icons, so that when sharing after clicking on this achor link, the url is retained when sharing via the other buttons.

now my question: is it possible to delete this "url appendage" directly when you click or to implement a complete solution via javascript?

here an example (only on desktop): https://www.benzmedia.de/hosting/

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem is like set the href's value of the anchor tag attribute is null.

suppose, your anchor tag id is: data.

```
<a id="data" href="https://www.w3schools.com">go w3school</a>
```

select id=data , then set the attribute of href is blank.
after that your provided link is not working.

```
data.setAttribute('href','');
```